# Laravel date before_equal is allowing all dates through

Tags: laravel, validation, date, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

```
 $DOB = $request->input('DOB');
 $allowed = Carbon::now()->subYears(26)->format('Y-m-d');

 $validatedData = $request->validate(
    ['DOB' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:'.$allowed],
  );

  <input type="date" name="DOB" class="form-control" required>
```

I am having a hard time validating dates in Laravel.

If I enter 01/01/2018 in the form, the validation does not catch it. Below it what is returned if I dd() the variables.

```
dd([$DOB, $allowed]);

array:2 [▼
 0 => "2018-01-01"
 1 => "1992-04-26"
]
```

No idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: What's the result of `dd(\Validator::make(['DOB' => '2018-01-01'], ['DOB' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:1992-04-26'])->passes());`?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir, false

Comment: Did you enter `2018-01-01` or `01/01/2018`?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir, Form asks for mm/dd/yyyy, but when I dd(), it auto converts to yyyy-mm-dd. Which is peculiar

Comment: I missed the HTML in your question, the `input` automatically converts the date. Can you post the whole controller method?

Comment: I ended up doing a php artisan make:request with a hook. Thank you though.